# Angular Http Get Always Returns Status 0 for ng-click

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've been trying to get this to work, conceptually its simple click the tag and it calls a REST service that returns a JSON result, where i grab the country name and show it just as a test.
I'm using angular.

Every time I click it returns with a Status of 0. 
believe this is the plnker http://plnkr.co/edit/k3Z6Ufi734oYE4ciVJs8

**This is the HTML**
not much to it just call the GetInfo function via ng-click

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainModule">
<!--http://plnkr.co/edit/k3Z6Ufi734oYE4ciVJs8-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>    
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

        <div><b ng-click="GetInfo()">Click Me</b></div>

    <b>{{AdditionalInfo.geobytescountry}}</b>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is the Angular Back end.

```
var app = angular.module('mainModule', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  var cityDetailsUrl = "http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?callback=?&fqcn=new%20york,%20NY,%20United%20States";

   $scope.AdditionalInfo =  {};

   $scope.GetInfo =  function ()
   {
       $http.get(cityDetailsUrl)
              .success(function(data, status, header, config){
                      console.log('ok'); 
                      $scope.AdditionalInfo = data; 
                      console.log(data);})
              .error(function(data, status, header, config){
                      console.log('error'); 
                      $scope.AdditionalInfo = data; 
                      console.log(status);});
   }


});
```

the link provided should result in a JSON response as I tried id in the web browser. 
similar to this "geobytesinternet":"US","geobytescountry":"United States"

Comment: http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/ Is a blog entry on an alternative to using jsonp.  I personally prefer using CORS without jsonp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Plunker example this seems to be two problems.

First of all it seems like you want to use `JSONP`, so you should use `$http.jsonp` instead of `$http.get`, simple `$http.get` will fail because of same origin policy violation.

Another problem is that your URL should have the attribute `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` instead of `callback=?` for JSONP to work. After fixing these two issues the code seems to work properly.

See an edited version of the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SYB9TI29MOHfNPw1jjQT

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Since the server is returning jsonp, not json, modify your url to contain `JSON_CALLBACK` to be:
`http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&fqcn=new%20york,%20NY,%20United%20States`

And use `$http.jsonp` instead of `$http.get`. Here's the modified Plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Jcs4rQHbINZyLwEN3VeR?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the help want to give the correct answer to both of you.